# Calendar.MONTH retorna mês incorreto

Tags: java, android, data

Estou desenvolvendo um método onde posso pegar a data, mês e ano, para criar uma chave de segurança para conectar no servidor. Só que já verifiquei a data do meu emulador e do meu celular está correta, mas o mês vem com mês anterior.

Meu código está da seguinte forma.

```
Calendar c = new Calendar.getIntance();
 int ano = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int dia =c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema com o `Calendar`?
O ano e o dia está vindo corretos, somente o mês está vindo com um mês anterior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH):

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars i**s JANUARY which is 0**; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

Os meses são indexados a partir de *0*, Janeiro,  e Dezembro, *11*.

Para resolver, basta adicionar *1*:

```
int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH + 1);
```

O porque do Java usar [zero como base de inicialização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) talvez seja devido a ser esse o padrão do C. Java é uma [linguagem descendente do C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages).

O motivo para ser *zero* a base de inicialização, pode ser resumido [nessa resposta do Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/110836):

> O índice em um `array` não é realmente um índice. É simplesmente um deslocamento que é a distância desde o início do `array`.
>
> O primeiro elemento é no início do `array` de modo que não há
>   distância. Por conseguinte, o deslocamento é *zero*.

[**Aqui**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list) tem uma lista que mostra quais linguagens usam *0* ou *1* como base de inicialização.

Mais informações:

- [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)
- [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)